# Error on Pytz - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pytz

I'm having this problem with ptyz:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.timezone('US/Mountain')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "stdin", line 1, in module
 File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/__init__.py", line 181, in timezone
   _tzinfo_cache[zone] = build_tzinfo(zone, fp)
 File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz-2013b-py2.6.egg/pytz/tzfile.py", line 78, in build_tzinfo
   while ttinfo[i][1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have two accounts in a server, and two different installations of pytz, though they are a copy of each other. In one of them, pytz works as a charm, but in the other one I have this error. It looks like an error inside ptyz, but it cannot be, because pytz works fine in the other account.

Has anyone handled this befor or have any idea of what may be causing this?

**Update:**

This error just happen when the script is called by a page, and that's the exact last message:

```
build_tzinfo(zone='US/Michigan', fp=<closed file '/home/user/.local/lib/python2...e-packages/pytz/zoneinfo/US/Michigan', mode 'rb'>)
```

and `fp` is a variable inside **init**.py that just receives it:

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

It seems that the file is found, opened, but not really opened. I found at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html that there are differences between linux and windows on the way they see binary files. My server runs Linux and, again, on the other account, with the same instalation, pytz works as a charm.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same library by both accounts? It seems like pytz is installed in user's home directory so if you run it under different accounts it might use different installations.

Comment: Compare the output of `import pytz; print pytz.__file__` in both installations. They're probably not the same.

Comment: Or, if they _are_ the same, does account #1 have read access to all of the files in account #0's `site-packages`? It may be that `pytz` failed to read its database files and just didn't report the error as nicely as it could have…

Comment: The different accounts have different installations of pytz. Thanks for that, I edited my question to give this information. The outputs of  `print pytz.__file__` are `__init__.pyc` in each account, both in its place and with the same permissions. I don't need that the two accounts see the same installation, I can't figure why the two installations doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happened:

After I updated my question, I noticed that the problem was with python opening a binary file. A friend told me to check the software I was using to send files to the server (Filezila), and there was three types of transfer: ASCII, Binary or Automatic. The software was set to Automatic. I send again the binary files in the binary transfer mode and it worked.